# Float left removes the hyperlinks

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I know this is popular problem. I tried everything but still I could not make this work.
here is my html and css.

```css
.unodered-item {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.item {
  height: 140px;
  width: 220px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background: pink;
  //background-image: url("../resourses/tutorial-thumbnails/thumbnail.png");
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a.item-link {
  height: 140px;
  width: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="recommended-list-items">
    <ul class="unodered unodered-recommended">
      <li class="unodered-item">
        <div class="item item'+ x +'">
          <a class="item-link" href="tutorial-player.jsp"></a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Help!!!

Comment: adding float:left to a.item-link does not work?

Comment: reset display on a with any value(but inline) to be able to size it....

Answer (score 0):

It is not hidden. It is just empty. Add `display: block` to your `a.item-link`.

```
a.item-link {
    height: 140px;
    width: 220px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add display:block or float:left to .item-link

```
a.item-link {
    height: 140px;
    width: 220px;
    display: block;
}
```

or

```
a.item-link {
    height: 140px;
    width: 220px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the a tag outside of the div block. Is this what you want?

```
<div class="recommended-list-items">
        <ul class="unodered unodered-recommended">
          <li class="unodered-item"><a class="item-link" href="tutorial-player.jsp"><div class="item item'+ x +'"></div></a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I want a clickable div with a hyperlink

Comment: I dont know what the problem is. It still does not work